# extconf.rb: "fails to build native gem extension"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos

I have a VPS running CentOS, and I have ths message when I try to install `Rails`, `Passenger` or anything else.

```
[athos@athoscastro bin]$ gem install rails
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /home/athos/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/athos/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

I have all the dependencies installed (everything related to this on Google says about dependecy) but the error still persists.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev` (`yum` respective for CentOS.)

Comment: @mudasobwa `libxml2-dev` and `libxslt-dev` are not found here... only `libxml2` and `libxslt`. i'm using epel already

Answer (score 0):

Did you install dev packages?

```
sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel zlib-devel
```

and

```
yum install libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
```

Comment: Try the second one yum install libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel